# sentences that have at least 2 numbers or more in SED

Tags: regex, ubuntu, sed

Using only SED (ubuntu20.4), I need to print sentences that have at least 2 numbers or more.
Then, print only the first two words of the sentence.
I was able to perform the second part, but the first goal, I do not know how to perform.

this is the file:

```
 ab      c1d
dea   1 a zz7 www44
xy12    abc xyz
xy1 ab XYZ
xy ab X2YZ 3
```

And this is what I've done so far:

```
sed -E "s/^[ ]*([^ ]+[ ]+[^ ]+).*/\1/" $* > 123
```

Comment: Hi MKLLKM - I'm not really clear what you mean by "I need to print sentences that have at least 2 numbers or more." Are you working with existing text, or are you trying to create them? And do you mean actual sentences, or just lines? And by "have at least 2 numbers", do you mean contain two numerals in the line?

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanna use `sed` to print the first 2 words of string that contains at least 2 digits :

```sh
sed -nE '/[0-9]{2,}/p' ./yourFile.txt | sed -E 's/^\s*(\S+\s+\S+).*$/\1/'
```

- `/[0-9]{2,}` : strings that contains at least 2 digits
- `/^\s*(\S+\s+\S+).*$` : line that begins with 0 or many space, then capturing a group of `(1 or many non space char)(1 or many space char)(1 or many non space char)` and then any

EXAMPLE :

input :

```
 ab      c1d
dea   1 a zz7 www44
xy12    abc xyz
xy1 ab XYZ
xy ab X2YZ 3
```

output :

```
dea   1
xy12    abc
```

and if you want to get rid of multi space char between the first two words of each line you can pipe it one more time into sed :

```sh
sed -nE '/[0-9]{2,}/p' ./yourFile.txt 
    | sed -E 's/^\s*(\S+\s+\S+).*$/\1/' 
    | sed -E 's/\s+/ /'
```

- `s/\s+/ /` : `s` for substistute, `\s+` for capturing all consecutive space char, `/ /` for replacing it by just one space char

so in that case output will be :

```
dea 1
xy12 abc
```

Comment: You do not need the `sed -E 's/\s+/ /'` (the third piped `sed` command). Just use `sed -E 's/^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+).*$/\1 \2/'` before

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sh
sed -En '/[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9]/{s/^ *([^ ]+ +[^ ]+).*/\1/p}' file
awk '/[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9]/{print $1" "$2}' file
```

In both cases, a line with at least two digits is detected with the `/[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9]/` regex (digit, any zero or more chars other than digits, a digit), and then in the `sed` solution, the first two words are captured and the rest is matched and removed, and in the `awk` solution, only the first two words (that are the first and second fields) are returned concatenated with a space.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/yoxDjF):

```sh
s=' ab      c1d
dea   1 a zz7 www44
xy12    abc xyz
xy1 ab XYZ
xy ab X2YZ 3'
sed -En '/[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9]/{s/^([^[:space:]]+ +[^[:space:]]+).*/\1/p}' <<< "$s"
echo "Now, awk..."
awk '/[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9]/{print $1" "$2}' <<< "$s"
```

Both return the first words, `sed` keeps all spaces intact:

```
dea   1
xy12    abc
xy ab
```

`awk` keeps just one:

```
dea 1
xy12 abc
xy ab
```

Comment: he explicitly asks only `sed`, so no `awk`, but that's cool too :)

Comment: @SimonDehaut I have been watching these `sed`, `awk`, etc. tags for more than two years every day, and constantly see people posting awk solutions to sed-tagged questions and vice versa.

Comment: yep I totally agree but the web is full of mixed sed/awk answers, and it's harder to find sed only solution. If original poster wants sed and awk mixed solution ... better time to googling it...